# VB.net Visual Studio 2003 Reading Data from Excel Table

Tags: database, vb.net, excel

I am trying to read data from an Excel table into a DataSet however I get an error: "No value given for one or more required parameters." I've done some research and learned that this error usually occurs when a required value is empty ("" in the case of a string) or null. Below is my code.

```
cnExcel = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection( _
              "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " & _
              "data source=" & FileName & "; " & _
              "Extended Properties=Excel 5.0;")
cdImport = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter( _
              "select * from [" & cSheetName & "$] order by StoreID, ItemID", cnExcel)
dsImport = New System.Data.DataSet
cdImport.Fill(dsImport)
cnExcel.Close()
```

The error is occuring on cdImport.Fill(dsImport) presumably because there is nothing to fill dsImport with.

After doing some debugging I find that the Server Version field of cnExcel is: error: an excpetion of type: {System.InvalidOperationException} occured

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone was wondering about how this got resolved:
I wound up just sending the excel file as a csv to my server. The server then runs a stored procedure on the file which returns a table to my application. A dataset is then filled from this table.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to put additional quotes around the `Extended Properties=Excel 5.0;` part of your connection string (see [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-jet-ole-db-4-0/) for more information)

Comment: Also, I noticed in your code you don't explicitly do a `cnExcel.Open()` but you do have a `cnExcel.Close()`. Perhaps try doing that (opening the connection) before filling the DataSet

Comment: Also, `Excel 5.0` seems a bit old...if you scroll down [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819) page to the "How to Use the Microsoft Jet OLE DB Provider" section it specifies some Excel versions to use & when to use them

Comment: Thanks again for the responses, but I tried both of your suggestions and neither worked. Resulted in the same error.

Comment: The only other things I can think of are putting the column names in your ORDER BY clause in square brackets, e.g. `[StoreID]`. 

Also, other connection strings I have seen have had HDR=Yes as part of their extended properties (like on [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-jet-ole-db-4-0/)). I think you need this if you want to use the header row of the sheet as the column names instead of just using auto-generated Excel column names.

Sorry I can't be of more help

Comment: HDR=Yes is the default behavior but I have tried added it, just in case, with no luck. I know it isn't my ORDER BY clause since I removed the entire thing with no luck. I did try adding the brackets, though, which did not work either. Thanks again for what you've contributed. On a side note, I noticed that adding in cnExcel.Open() gets rid of the Server Version error. Now it become 04.00.0000. Not sure if this is correct or not.

Comment: I think that indicates you can connect/open the sheet OK. The only other thing I can think of might be for some reason it doesn't like the sheet name in your query...do you get an error if you try and query a blank Excel file with the default sheet names (e.g. Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3)?

Comment: I know the sheet name is correct because I am extracting it from the file itself. Also I was getting different errors about the sheet name before I used this method, so I do not think sheet name is a problem. Another thought would be that the connection might be timing out before it can parse all the data, since the excel file is  large.

Comment: Nope doesn't have to do with connection timeout.